# How to specifically add on python

Tags: python

How do you add 1 to a users age, e.g if I asked the user their age, how do you add 1 to it? Please could I have specific answers as I am very new to Python. Thank You.

Comment: Can you show a little bit of your work? What do you have so far?

Comment: what is a `user` in your example?

Comment: Please provide a more complete explanation of your goal and show some code written so we can better assist. A good starting point is [the official docs](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/).
That said, search the site for similar questions

Comment: What was wrong with the answers you got the last two times you asked this question?

Comment: age= input ('How old are you?')
age += 1                                                          this is what i have done so far

Comment: Sorry for the duplicates its just that as I am new to python I look for simple answers therefore i produce duplicates for varied answers

Comment: Ok so what is missing in your solution? The answers in this thread and the one you opened before give everything you need. You need to research the answers a bit to understand them. Duplicates will be closed.

Comment: Please do not post duplicate questions: it's an abuse of the system, and successive questions will be closed. The downvotes you've received on all your questions are a reflection of the quality of your questions. See [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for guides on asking a good, on-topic question.

Comment: Sorry guys, I guess you can close all my questions, this was just a one time thing for me. I guess I am not really suitable for python as I am only 11 years old :(

Answer (score 3):

Things in python have a type.  If the age is already a numeric type (e.g. `int`, `float`) you can just do `age = age + 1` or `age += 1`.

If the age is a string, you'll need to convert it to a numeric type.

For example, if you do:

```
age = raw_input('How old are you?')
print 'After your birthday, you will be', age+1
```

You'll get an error because `age` will be a string.

Therefore, you'd need to do:

```
age = raw_input('How old are you?')
age = int(age)
print 'After your birthday, you will be', age+1
```

Answer (score 2):

You should look at [`input()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input) and [`raw_input()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#input) for requesting input from the user, and the `+=` operator for adding to an existing integer.

Try the [Input and Output](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html) section of the Python documentation for more.

Answer (score 0):

```
def main():
    age = int(input("Enter your age: "))
    print("In one year, you will be " + (age + 1))


main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any sort of programming experience?  If not, I would recommend taking an online course from udacity.com or http://www.codecademy.com/.

To get input from a user, you need to prompt a user for their age.

```
age = raw_input('Please enter your age: ')
```

This will assign age to whatever the user enters.
Whenever you get a value with raw_input, it has a type str, so you'll need to call int or float on it.

```
age = int(age)
```

Or you could have done:

```
age = int(raw_input('Please enter your age: '))
```

To add one, you can do

```
age = age + 1
```

or

```
age += 1
```

Comment: nope, `age` above will be a string, not an integer.

Comment: Woops, I'lll fix that...